# C++ auto return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, auto

I wrote a function that looks like that:

```
auto fn(auto x) {
    return x;
}
```

I called it twice with different arguments:

```
std::cout << fn(3124) << std::endl;
std::cout << fn("hello world") << std::endl;
```

It works fine, but I don't understand why - I thought the compiler deduces a constant return type for the function - int (due to the first call - fn(3124)).
It seems that the compile-time generated function looks like

```
template<typename T>;
T fn(T x) {
   return x;
}
```

I can't figure out why.
Please explain.

Comment: Different specializations of a function template should be considered *different functions*.

Comment: Useful thing to keep in mind: every `auto` you write is a distinct `auto`. The two `auto`s in your `fn` are totally independent. The same is true of `auto fn(auto x, auto y) { return x+ y;}` - this can take objects of two different types and return an object of a third different type.

Answer (score 11):

```
auto fn(auto x)
```

is a C++20 version of

```
template<class X>
auto fn(X x)
```

As such, it would be instantiated for every argument type it was called with, having different return type for each different argument type. That feature is called [Abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Comment: Oh, you're right. I confused it with something else. We can do `auto x` now, but not `T<auto> x` where `T` is some template.